# Python for loop appending to every key in dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, iteration

I'm iterating over a list of tuples and a list of strings. The strings are identifiers for the items in the list. I have a dictionary that has the strings identifiers as keys and has an initially empty list for each value. I want to append something from the tuple list to each key. A simplified version of what I'm doing is:

```
tupleList = [("A","a"),("B","b")]
stringList = ["Alpha", "Beta"]
dictionary = dict.fromkeys(stringList, [])  # dictionary = {'Alpha': [], 'Beta': []}
for (uppercase, lowercase), string in zip(tupleList, stringList):
    dictionary[string].append(lowercase)
```

I would expect this to give `dictionary = {'Alpha': ['a'], 'Beta': ['b']}`, but instead I find that `{'Alpha': ['a', 'b'], 'Beta': ['a', 'b']}`. Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't lowercase always be the second item in the tuple, since I'm matching (uppercase, lowercase) against tupleList?

Comment: My bad, I realised my mistake after posting, sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that you share the list between the two keys by reference.

What happens is that `dict.fromkeys` doesn't create a new list for each key, but gives the reference to the same list to all the keys. the rest of your code looks correct :)

Instead of doing that you should use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), basically it is a dict, which creates new values if they don't exist, and retrieves them if they do (and removes the need for the if / else when inserting an item to check if it already exists). It's really useful in these kinds of situations:

```
from collections import defaultdict

tupleList = [("A","a"),("B","b")]
stringList = ["Alpha", "Beta"]
dictionary = defaultdict(list) # Changed line
for (uppercase, lowercase), string in zip(tupleList, stringList):
    dictionary[string].append(lowercase)
```

Comment: Instead of `dictionary = defaultdict(lambda: [])` you could also write `dictionary = defaultdict(list)`, which I find more readable.

Comment: Thanks, it really is a lot better :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when you call `dict.fromkeys` and pass it a list as a default item for each key, python uses the same list, lists are not immutable so one change to a list affects it everywhere it is referenced, what you can do to get around this is to call `dict.fromkeys` without any argument, this sets the default items as None, then you have an if statement to check if it's None and initialize two different lists. and then subsequently you append to that list if it's not None (when it already exists).

```
tupleList = [("A","a"),("B","b")]
stringList = ["Alpha", "Beta"]
dictionary = dict.fromkeys(stringList)  # dictionary = {'Alpha': [], 'Beta': []}
for (uppercase, lowercase), string in zip(tupleList, stringList):
    #print(id(dictionary[string])) uncomment this with your previous code
    if dictionary[string] is None:
        dictionary[string] = [lowercase]
    else:
        dictionary[string].append(lowercase)
```